# How to use multidimensional checkbox v-model in vuejs

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

Suppose i have some subjects which has conditions and groups.
How can i load those first time and checked in update mood in vuejs?

```
<div v-for="(sub, Index) in subjects">

  <b>{{ sub }} </b>   
    <label v-for="(subconlist) in sub['subCon']">
                                        <input type="checkbox" 
                                        :value="subconlist.id"
                                         :key="subconlist.id"
                                       >
                                        <span>{{subconlist.name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                                    </label>
                                     <label v-for="clsgrlist in sublist['acGr']">
                                        <input type="checkbox">
                                        <span>{{clsgrlist.academic_group_name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                                    </label>
  </div>
     <button @click="saveOrUpdate()" >Save   </button>
  </div>
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Fawel/m9o84yjk/)

the table where i will save it : sub_id,condition_ids,group_ids
I have to save data based on checked value in the table with comma separated.
How can i get checkbox checked if it already found in the table, i mean when update?
I need to get subjectconditon or group ids basis on each subject when click on save button.

Comment: Please make sure your fiddle works

Comment: please see now. Corrected the fiddle @MaciejKwas

Comment: you are requested to check the fiddle.  @MaciejKwas

Comment: Confirmed- fiddle works!

Comment: Sadly enough, I can not understand your question

Comment: I want to get all selected conditions and groups ids obj with repective selected subject id when click on save. And also want deafult checked if value mached in db. I mean id goup ids: [1,2] present under physics then those group must be checked when loop under physics subject. expected result something like: [{1:{1,2},{2,3}},{2:{1},{1,3}}] @MaciejKwas

Comment: Thanks for your good attitude to help me. I did it !@MaciejKwas

Comment: you can help me doing one thing . How can i get the subject  checked when anything (group or conditions)inside that subject is checked? @MaciejKwas

Comment: please, post it as a separate question. I would use filter for that.